How to define a type equivalent to multidimentional vector
How to work out the following code?
template<int D> typename matrix;
template<int D> using matrix<D> = vector<matrix<D - 1>>;
using matrix<1> = vector<int>;

This code isn't able to be complied. So how to implement the idea?

I would suggest you abstract it out into a separate class. Will simplify quite a lot of things for you, especially operations on it.

a nested vector is a terrible data structure to begin with.

Multi-dimensional containers are not that easy in C++, because of the way iterators are defined. I once tried to give a try but it was 6 years ago and the language has evolved since that time. If it helps I can show what I obtained after some improvements on CodeReview

@SergeBallesta Well there is std::mdspan which can help a lot.

@PepijnKramer: Nice pick! C++ has indeed greatly evolved for the last 6 years...

Specialization is best done with class templates. I am not going to show you how to nest a vector but how to nest a foo:
#include <string>

template <typename T> struct foo {};

template <int D> struct bar_impl {
    using type = foo<typename bar_impl<D-1>::type>;
};

template <> struct bar_impl<1> {
    using type = foo<int>;
};

// now you can use an alias for convenience:
template <int D>
using bar = typename bar_impl<D>::type;

Live Demo
A nested vector is a terrible data structure. Take std::vector<int> for example. It shines because of its data locality. All elements are stored in contiguous memory. Because the elements are dynamically allocated, the ints in a std::vector<std::vector<int>> are scattered around in memory and will cause lots of cache misses which is nowadays one of the biggest factors for performance. You should rather consider to use a flat std::vector<int> for any dimensions with appropriate index transformations implemented in a custom class.

Shouldn't be template <int D> struct bar_impl ?

@pptaszni indeed. It was some self inflicted vandalism when I was planning for the alias, then decided to not include it and eventually did inlucde it without testing the code. Thanks
